# "Honest living money"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, difference, sentence-structure

**Honest work** is a job that you work fairly hard at. 
**an honest living:** I’m just trying to earn an honest living (=earn money by working hard). [[Source]](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/honest)

I am going to say:

> **Money it's made from an honest work** is blessed.

I was wondering whether according to my provided definitions, we substitute the bold construction above with the following one:

- **An honest living** is blessed

without any change in meaning. 
If no, then please let me know why?

Comment: Honest work is not the same as 'a job that you work fairly hard at'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *Honest work* is not necessarily hard work: it might be something you find quite easy, but it's honest (not criminal, cheating, or getting paid for doing nothing).

Secondly *Money it's made from an honest work* is not English. I think you mean *Money that's made from honest work* (or more naturally *money earned from honest work*).

Thirdly, in combination with *make* or *earn*, *an honest living* often means "money earned from honest work", but without one of those verbs, its usual meaning is the life lived, not about earnings; so no, it doesn't necessarily have the same meaning as your previous phrase.

Comment: I have never seen 'an honest living' meaning anything other than 'an income got from honest work'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I partly agree.  Looking for _honest living_ in the GloWbE corpus, the vast majority are collocated with _make_ or _earn_, and they all mean the income. The few cases which do not have those verbs do not seem to have that meaning (eg "Oh, would that men would leave the city, its splendour and its tumult and its gold, and return to wood and field and simple, honest living! "). I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: What the people seem to do in the wood and field seems to be a non-count thing, with no preceding article. Believe me, I have lived and worked in the UK for more decades than I care to admit, and I know what 'an honest living' is, and how outlandish (or not) the phrase is. Corpus or no corpus.