# An incompetent person in some actions (Informal AE)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, idioms, expressions, idiom-request

**Edited:** I was wondering what is the AE idiom / expression in casual / informal speech which describes someone with little or no ability to do something well? 
Such people often have a great difficulty in doing some specific deals. When it comes to some particular actions (say dating a girl here,) they are not considered as capable people. I.e. they are physically awkward and perform actions in an awkward way.

Let me give you an example:

> - I don't like finding my life companion online. 
>    Turning a penpal to a soulmate is something that a / an ........ (person) would do and not a person who can manage their own affairs. 
>    I would definitely prefer to be single rather than date someone online.

Some options cross my mind; such as "[ineffectual](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/ineffectual)", "[weakling](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/weakling)", "[incompetent](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/incompetent)", "[incapable](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/incapable)" and "[bumbling](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/bumbling)".
As you know, all these words have some overlaps, but first most of them sound a bit stilted or at least formal in terms of formality; on the other hand I am not quite confident which one encapsulates my explanations regarding such a person.

PS. I am well aware that this is a subjective matter and has its own pros and cons! However, that was a scenario that crossed my mind out of the blue and I decided to bring it up here for clarification and it has nothing to do with my mindset. I wonder if you could consider it from the linguistic perspective.

Comment: I think there is no one word for this. The one you want depends heavily on context, and on a nuanced analysis of what you want to say. In addition to the words you suggest, consider "timid", "hesitant", "shy", "bumbling", "unfocused", ... Roget's Thesaurus may be your friend.

Comment: Thank you @Ethan Bolker, but in my view your suggestions have nothing to do with my need! I am talking about a klutzy person who performa some actions quite awkwardly! Not someone who is timid / shy etc. Besides, not only was I looking for a single word, but also an idiom or expression.

Comment: Your question is all over the map. Maybe edit it down, to one specific question.  If the example is the question, get rid of the rest.  If it isn't, it is so jarring and disconnected from any questions of human character to be disturbing and distracting. If someone tried to help with your question they wouldn't know which part to keep and edit and which to delete. Points for connecting Boxing Skills, Financial Accumen and Online Dating Stigma. At this time I unfortunately can't think of one particular expression that encapsulates the character flaw they all demonstrate.

Comment: Point taken @Blind Spots. I edited the thread. Please let me know about the clarifications.

Comment: @A-friend - I don't understand.  Your example does not support your request.  Turning a penpal into a soulmate is something a *klutzy* person would do?  That doesn't make any sense. Dropping the knife on their foot while they were cutting vegetables is something a klutzy person would do.  Timid, hesitant, and shy fit much better with your penpal example.

Comment: I might call that person a *goofball*.  But goofball might be a very localized usage.

Comment: Turning a penpal into a soul mate sounds like something wonderful. What's so ***inept*** about that?

Comment: I see @Elliek. let me try it with some other examples. :) I am looking for a word which can be used in order to define someone who lacks enough capability to perform some actions which require some capabilities / abilities. For instance, say making money! Although there are many ways to earn money, however, there are many people who are unable (say due to the lack of enough courage to go out and find a way) to find a way! Or say a student who has finished his studies 3 years ago, but still unemployed! Or suppose someone who doesn't know how should fight for his rights!

Comment: Or imagine a submissive child who other children use his toys and he just and looking at this eats him from inside but prefers to stay calm, because "doesn't know" what have to do! Or a woman who's husband cheats him, but just keeps calm, because she lacks the needed capability to fend for herself and ask for her primary rights to be served! I hope I'm getting my point across now.

Comment: @A-friend - Aha!  You are looking for the word **inept**.  The definition fits perfectly.  It even hints that the word could imply clumsiness.  I see that you mention it in one of your replies.  Inept covers a broad range of topics and inefficiencies.  It should work nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much @Elliek. May I ask you to answer to this question so that I could accept it?

Comment: Inept is not an idiom nor expression   It is however an excellent synonym for incompetent.  incompetence is not the most obvious explanation for most of your examples. If you really believe  that to be the case it seems to indicate inexperience, a lack of information, and/or personal  prejudice.  I would caution you to avoid describing anything other than incompetence as such, given how it will reflect back on you.  You will be judged by your judgements.

Comment: Your examples: 1. Physically ackward, 2. A person who dates online 2. A person who can't manage their 'affairs', 3. One who can't make money, 4. A cowardly person, 5. a person who is educated yet is unemployed for 3 years, 6. One who is ignorant of how to advocate for themselves, 7. A submissive child who is upset by their treatment but accepts it due to l a lack of information, 8. A wife who is mistreated but endures it because she doesn't have the ability to support herself.  I don't see ineptitude in these examples, but the examples are inconsistent and lack insight and/or compassion.

Comment: I see @Blind Spots. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for the community, and taken together with the OP's question history, fits a pattern that looks like tweaking the "real agenda" into an on-topic structure, often, as in this case, creating a vague puzzle that is unlikely to be constructive. This appears to ultimately be a request for writing assistance which would belong on, eg, https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [OP's question history](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/5652/a-friend). [This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302067/honest-living-money) exemplifies the pattern I have noticed. It looks like, in reality, a disguised "how do I phrase / better phrase this," but with whatever they are actually trying to write disguised in some kind of homology (because they've learned that "help me write this" questions tend to be closed as off-topic). Such homologies often do not make sense or present a puzzle that I suspect consumes a significant amount of effort from 2/

Comment: community members, generates a high number of close votes and reviews, and ultimately results in a low ratio of constructive answers. If my sense of the situation is more-or-less correct, I think that ELL can still certainly serve the user and the community, *if* the help section is for this site is carefully reviewed, and more care is exercised before deciding which questions to post and how to construct them. 3/

Comment: With all due respect @Jim Reynolds I 100% disagree; my history (as you mentioned), is a strong justification of this claim that I hardly ever tried to ask people to proofread something for me or help me to write something! If some of my questions draw nobody's attention, it won't decrease the value of those questions'! Somehow, they might be against some of the forum's regulations, however, these paradoxes are not intentional at all, while in my view, these miscommunications are rooted in cultural / lingual gaps for communication.

Comment: @A-f Maybe useful to discuss with the community in chat or meta? I support you with your wish to collaborate with others, whatever your goals are and whatever you want to contribute. My sense is that something’s not working well, at least sometimes.

Comment: This is the way forum works due to the rules and regulations @Jim Reynolds. I don't think there is something wrong with posting any sort of English-concerned questions here; worst case scenario we can ask the OP not to send similar questions in the future! However, if you wish to go ahead with this discussion, in order to avoid prolonging this discussion, we can keep going in a specific chatroom! It might be helpful to remove suspicious layers of my intention. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In New York at least, we'd often call such a person a "schlemiel". If that doesn't work for you, then I'd recommend a thesaurus, as Ethan Bolker suggested. E.g., there are plenty of synonyms here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/schlemiel

Answer (score 1):

"All thumbs" might do for physical ineptitude. Not so much for "making money or dealing with the unprecedented.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/all--thumbs

Comment: As you mentioned, "all thumbs" is used for "physical ineptitude," as it goes with "clumsy" and "klutz(y)". They mostly refer to someone with weak control over holding things and who usually ends of dropping or breaking them. Whereas I was going to accentuate someone's lack of competence in doing something. Someone not skillful enough to manage to do something like making money, living alone, cooling etc.